# How to make Ansible apply Playbook tasks per host in full in serial?

Tags: ansible

At the moment, Ansible executes all tasks in parallel on all hosts.

How do I make it apply Playbook tasks per host in full in serial?

Answer (score 0):

From [Rolling Update Batch Size](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#rolling-update-batch-size)

You can define how many hosts Ansible should manage at a single time by using the **serial** keyword

```
- name: test play
  hosts: webservers
  serial: 1
```

Ansible 2.2 has more powerful feature set for batch sizes

Comment: I have added this at the top of the playbook, but I am pretty sure it executed all of the tasks in parallel.

Comment: May be I didn't understand your question. You want to execute your play on one host at a time?

Comment: Yes. Entire play on one a host at a time.

Comment: Just put the list of hosts in a bash for loop: `for host in ${host_list}; do ansible-playbook my_play $host; done`

Comment: @TadasŠubonis can you post the part of the play where you specify `serial`. And what is the ansible version you are using?

Comment: `serial: 1` makes sure each task get executed host by host. @TadasŠubonis do you mean you want to run a play host by host? (ie. host A finishes all tasks, then host B and so on)

Comment: @ChrisLam Yes - host by host